# Unguided speech to text conversion

Tags: speech-to-text, cmusphinx, sphinx4

I am trying to come up with a way to convert speech to text. I am trying to use [Sphinx](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/sphinx4/1.0%20beta6/) to attain this. What I mean by unguided speech to text is that, the speaker is not bound to speak from a definite set of sentences. Rather he might speak any sentence. So its not possible for me to have a grammar file, where each word is one of the alternative pre-written in the grammar file. I understand that I would have to train Sphinx somehow to do this.

But I am a beginner in sphinx. How to start training Sphinx to convert unguided speech? Is it possible to attain unguided conversion with Sphinx?

Answer (score 0):

The task you are up to is, as of right now, is not yet possible to complete, at least not with satisfying accuracy.

As for the Sphinx-based solution: you will have to create dictionary with all the words to be recognized. There is no other way.

Once you have the dictionary, you can generate a simple n-gram model based on it, with ony unigrams - each unigram will be one word. The probability of each may be the same, or you may attempt to do some statistical analysis of the words that will be used.